# How to set cookies with python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, roblox

Im attempting to make a python script to login to roblox.com accounts. I was wondering how to set the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie to be able to remotely login to accounts.

I currently do not have any code as I dont know where to start. I am assuming it uses requests though.

Comment: a cookie is just a header of the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send cookies while using the `requests` library, set the `cookies` keyword argument as follows

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.cookies[".ROBLOSECURITY"] = "" // your .ROBLOSECURITY cookie goes here
```

Now if you make a request using the `Session`, it will include the .ROBLOSECURITY cookie in the headers.